# How to convert hexdump to text?

Tags: terminal, hexdump

I know that `xxd` is used to convert texts to hexdump but I want to do the opposite: convert an hex dump to text! Is there some command that I can use? Thanks for the help!

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/244025/tool-to-convert-a-file-of-hex-to-ascii-character-set (1st google hit)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

xxd can also convert the other way

```
xxd -r
```

Comment: I would like to do the same with hexdump but I haven't found any clue :-(